# How to change the caret up & down when doing accordion collapse

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Hi guys i am a newbie to vue js and currently i am making a accordion below to expand/collapse the accordion content but there's a problem i am facing which is the `<b-icon icon="caret-up-fill" class="view-less-icon " aria-hidden="true"></b-icon>` is not changing when i click . anyone can help me with this?

```
<div class="accordion" role="tablist">
              <b-card no-body class="mb-1"  style="border:none;">
                <b-card-header role="tab"  style="background-color:white; border: none;">
                  <b-row class="title"  v-b-toggle.my-details>
                      <b-col class="mt-3 mb-0 " cols='8'>  My Details</b-col>
                         <b-col class="mt-3 mb-0 view-more d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end" cols='4' aria-hidden="true">
                          <span class="when-opened"><b-icon icon="caret-down-fill" class="view-more-icon "  aria-hidden="true"></b-icon></span>
                         <span class="when-closed"><b-icon icon="caret-up-fill" class="view-less-icon "  aria-hidden="true"></b-icon></span>
                     </b-col>
                    </b-row>               
                </b-card-header>
                <b-collapse id="my-details"  accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
                  <b-card-body>
                    <b-card style="border:none;" >
                     <b-row  style="margin-bottom: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEF3F7;" >
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                          <b-col cols="12">                          
                              <b-row class="font-weight-bold">
                                  <b-col>Name</b-col>
                              </b-row>
                          </b-col>
                      </b-row>
                      <b-row >
                        <label for="date">Date</label>
                          <b-col cols="12">                          
                              <b-row class="font-weight-bold">
                                <b-form-input
                                  style="border-left: 0px;"
                                  type="text"
                                  name="my"
                                  v-model="form.date" 
                                  placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"
                                  @click="show_calendar('my_calendar')"
                              />                               
                              </b-row>
                          </b-col>
                      </b-row>
                      <b-row  >
                        <b-col class="mt-1 mb-0" > Description</b-col>
                           <b-col class="mt-2 mb-0 view-more d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end"  v-b-toggle.desc-collapse cols='4'>
                             <span class="when-opened"><b-icon icon="chevron-down" class="view-more-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end"  aria-hidden="true"></b-icon></span>
                             <span class="when-closed"><b-icon icon="chevron-right" class="view-less-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end" aria-hidden="true"></b-icon></span>
                            </b-col>
                      </b-row>       
                      <b-collapse id="desc-collapse">
                             <b-card style="border:none ;" >
                                hello world
                             </b-card>
                           </b-collapse>              
                 </b-card>
                  </b-card-body>
                </b-collapse>
              </b-card>


<style lang="scss" scoped>  
           @import "./../../_style.scss";

           .collapsed > .when-opened,
             :not(.collapsed) > .when-closed {
               display: none;
            }
       
   
       </style>
```

i would like to make it as when i am not clicking it will show caret down icon, when i click it will turn to caret up icon Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've created a code snippet for your issue. I removed two icons and just use `transform` in `CSS`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
})
```

```css
.not-collapsed .caretDownIcon {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.caretDownIcon {
    transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-vue/2.22.0/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.22.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />


<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.22.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <b-card no-body class="mb-1" style="border:none;">
    <b-card-header role="tab" style="background-color:white; border: none;">
      <b-row class="title" v-b-toggle.my-details>
        <b-col class="mt-3 mb-0 " cols='8'> My Details</b-col>
        <b-col class="mt-3 mb-0 view-more d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end" cols='4' aria-hidden="true">
          <b-icon class="caretDownIcon" icon="caret-down-fill" class="view-more-icon " aria-hidden="true"></b-icon>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-card-header>
    <b-collapse id="my-details" accordion="my-accordion" role="tabpanel">
      <b-card-body>
        <b-card style="border:none;">
          <b-row style="margin-bottom: 30px; border-bottom: 1px solid #EEF3F7;">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <b-col cols="12">
              <b-row class="font-weight-bold">
                <b-col>Name</b-col>
              </b-row>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <b-row>
            <label for="date">Date</label>
            <b-col cols="12">
              <b-row class="font-weight-bold">
                <b-form-input style="border-left: 0px;" type="text" name="my" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
              </b-row>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <b-row>
            <b-col class="mt-1 mb-0"> Description</b-col>
            <b-col class="mt-2 mb-0 view-more d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end" v-b-toggle.desc-collapse cols='4'>
              <span class="when-opened">
                <b-icon icon="chevron-down" class="view-more-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end" aria-hidden="true"></b-icon>
              </span>
              <span class="when-closed">
                <b-icon icon="chevron-right" class="view-less-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end" aria-hidden="true"></b-icon>
              </span>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <b-collapse id="desc-collapse">
            <b-card style="border:none ;">
              hello world
            </b-card>
          </b-collapse>
        </b-card>
      </b-card-body>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-card>
</div>
```